# Limit time picker in Material UI flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui, limit, timepicker

How can i limit time picker in material UI use flutter ?

i will limit the time from 8.00 to 16.00

here is my code

```dart
  void _selectTimeList(bool tipe, TimeOfDay tod, int index) async {
    final TimeOfDay? newTime = await showTimePicker(
        context: context,
        initialTime: tod,
        builder: (context, childWidget) {
          return MediaQuery(
              data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
                  // Using 24-Hour format
                  alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
              // If you want 12-Hour format, just change alwaysUse24HourFormat to false or remove all the builder argument
              child: childWidget!);
        });
    if (newTime != null) {
      setState(() {
        print("time = " + newTime.toString());
        if (tipe) {
          // _timeEnd = newTime;
          _listTimeEnd[index] = newTime;
        } else {
          // _timeStart = newTime;
          _listTimeStart[index] = newTime;
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

[image: Time Picker]

Comment: There is a GitHub [Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23717) on this which says it is not possible with the `showTimePicker`. I think it is better to use [`CupertinoTimerPicker `](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTimerPicker-class.html) or use packages like [time_picker_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/time_picker_widget)